# Ajax can't send data to php use GET

Tags: php, ajax

I create a html, and after I submit, the ajax should send a message to php, but my php doesn't get this data, please tell me how do I do, thank you.

```
function SendData(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "client.php?m=submit",
        success: function(data){
            alert("success");
        },
        error: function(data){
            alert("error");
        }
    });
}
```

php code always nothing, I know the m isn't exist, but I don't understand.

```
$message = isset($_GET['m']);
echo $message;
```

Comment: You need to look at the function [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

Comment: does the alert success appears ?

Comment: use the **data** option of your ajax object to send data

Comment: isset will return a Boolean value, which you cant echo, user `var_dump($message);` or directly `var_dump(isset($_GET['m']));`

Comment: the alert has run

Comment: sorry, can you tell more detail? I'm new, thank you

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you get a boolean with isset();

Do like this:

```
if(isset($_GET['m'])) {
  $message = $_GET['m'];
  echo $message;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try like

```
function SendData(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET", //send it through get method
        url: "client.php",
        data: { 
            m: submit   // Here you can send multiple parameters 
         },
        success: function(data){
            alert("success");
        },
        error: function(data){
            alert("error");
        }
    });
}
```

And you can get the data by

```
 if(isset($_GET['m'])){echo $_GET['m'];} //gives submit
```

Comment: Undefined index: m

Comment: please post code where you are using this SendData function

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to

```
$message = isset($_GET['m']) ? $_GET['m'] : null;
echo $message;
```

Answer (score 0):

the php `isset()` always determine if a variable is set and is not NULL. It will return `FALSE` if testing a variable that has been set to NULL. You can't echo the result outputted by isset directly using echo, use like this

```
$message= isset($_GET['m']) ? $_GET['m'] : ' ';
echo $message;
```

check the documention of isset here http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php